# A digraph related to permutations

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs

A finite sequence of distinct real numbers of length $n$ determines a linear order of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$, by mapping position to rank; call this the *permutation of the sequence*.

Consider the following digraph $P_n$.  The vertex set of $P_n$ comprises all the linear orders of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  Then an arrow connects vertex $v$ to vertex $w$ exactly when the permutation of $v$'s terminal length $n-1$ subsequence equals the permutation $w$'s initial length $n-1$ subsequence.

**Question 1**: Do these digraphs occur in the literature, and perhaps have a standard terminology and notation?

**Observation**: I have verified the following (which surprised me) by exhaustive computation:  $P_4$ admits 13063680 Hamiltonian paths originating from $v=(1,2,3,4)$ and every one of these extends to a Hamiltonian cycle!

**Question 2**: Is the previous observation a direct consequence of known theorem?

**Question 3**: Is anything known about the asymptotics of enumerations of Hamiltonian cycles in these digraphs?

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/49555

Comment: This sounds like a subgraph of a graph based on DeBruijn sequences.  You might check out the larger graph and its properties.

Comment: "Sounds like" can cover a multitude of sins.  One can attempt to represent a Hamiltonian of my sort by an actual sequence of reals (or natural numbers), but one finds that some Hamiltonians in $P_4$ require 23 distinct values (though others, as few as 5; these special cases only have a DeBruijn feel).

Comment: if you consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_graph, more precisely the one on $n^n$ vertices, then your graph is a subgraph where each vertex corresponds to a permutation of $n$ symbols, right?

Comment: No, Dima, unless I'm misunderstanding.  For example
4123 points to 2341 because 123 and 234 have the same position to rank function.  But they're *not* the same sequence of symbols, so no edge connects them in the DeBruijn graph.

Comment: Each Hamiltonian path prolongates to a Hamiltonian cycle exactly for the same reason as the complete domino chain has the same numbers on both ends: a Hamiltonian cycle is an Eulerian path in a graph on the permutations of $n-1$ symbols.

Comment: then this asks for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BEST_theorem

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you Ilya and Dima.  My application is mathematical music theory.  When and if I write something, may I simply credit you for your help?

Comment: @DavidFeldman, sure, you're welcome!

Comment: The factorization $13063680=2^9\cdot 3^6\cdot 5\cdot 7$ suggests that there might be a simple exact answer in general.

Comment: Right about the factorization...it drops out of the BEST_theorem at least in the form $6^6*280$.  The $280$ constitutes a count of arborescences but has an efficient expression as a determinant (though of perhaps a very large matrix as $n$ grows).

Comment: actually, I wonder if BEST really applies, as $P_n$ has degree $n$, whereas for BEST one would want degree $n+1$, at least naively.

Comment: For $n=5$ the number of Hamiltonian cycles is $4!^{24}\cdot 2^{11}\cdot 3^5\cdot 5^6\cdot 13^2\cdot 17\cdot 47$.

Comment: For $n =6$ the number is $5!^{120}\cdot 2^{32}\cdot 3^{29} \cdot 5^{20}\cdot 7^9\cdot 23\cdot 37^3\cdot 53\cdot 79\cdot 83\cdot 311^9\cdot 1993\cdot 5569\cdot 57679$.

Comment: For $n=7$ the number is $6!^{720}\cdot 176183413608273968258307195020261201995935498443817037880077$ $33015680734978977985994540951427241494888517320111715796104$ $01678883391824293568187890362411864333732042160720070054426$ $13973761520215432676342816642484823001649942753538184971817$ $00932653194251714270416078406552688838875907139437076885891$ $46604444975789292489211082309639859152636172062362845942377$ $16134182843447651691194901389583522511049879097164330759592530013$ (continued on next comment)

Comment: Continuation of previous comment: $02167802121430577869247906928263206218129022043438732817393$ $78238299321477251081703396523732122511001097003078223354740$ $21115543570842542767571682953869289112205514506240000000000000000000$. This must have a large prime factor since Maple has been taking many hours trying to factor it.

Comment: sage: factor(n)
2^307 * 3^120 * 5^19 * 7^128 * 11 * 13^3 * 19^44 * 31 * 43^44 * 47 * 61 * 113^6 * 127 * 131 * 139^2 * 241 * 1031 * 1481^2 * 1531 * 1621^2 * 1699^2 * 2801^3 * 5147 * 10607 * 47917^2 * 90803^2 * 548521 * 685367 * 2460593 * 47389957 * 2920679263^2 * 8428156447^2 * 216271121699 * 285106814092712039^2

Comment: takes 0.5 sec on my laptop (n is the number after $6!^{720}$)

Comment: One reason that the number of Hamiltonian cycles divided by $(n-1)!^{(n-1)!}$ factors quite a bit is the $S_n$-symmetry. A similar situation is at OEIS http://oeis.org/A120061. See also Chapter 10, Exercise 7(d) of my book *Algebraic Combinatorics*.